# Keep attribute data while converting XML file to shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: shapefile, convert, kml, google-earth-api

I want a map of particular area in shapefile format from Google Earth. I created a map using polygon method and save it as KML file format, but when I convert it from ".xml" to "shapefile" format using QGIS Desktop software I am not getting attribute data in the converted shapefile.

What should I do to keep my attribute data in shapefile format?

I am attaching image which showing no attribute data in QGIS:

[image: image which showing no attribute data in QGIS]

Answer (score 1):

When you create a polygon in Google Earth you should give a polygon a name, which I think you did not do. In the following example, I created a polygon and name it "Site 1", as you can see below:

[image]

Then when you want to save the newly created polygon, go to `My places` in Google Earth -> right-click the new polygon -> `Save Place As`. You can choose KML or KMZ both will work in QGIS. I am not sure from where you got the XML extension because there are just KML and KMZ extensions.

[image]

Finally, in QGIS Go to `Add Vector Layer` and browse to the KML/KMZ file in your hard disk, select the file you saved in the last step and load it.

[image]

When you open the attribute table, you will find the name "Site 1" is located under Name field.

Comment: Thanks but can you evaluate How to bring the name of places, location in the map as it was shown in google earth

Comment: If you stored information into the created KML, you need to parse the KML file using some python modules that are specialized for parsing HTML or XML files such as BeautifulSoup. But you cannot extract the name of places, location in the map as it as shown in google earth according to my knowledge.